# manager has damaged future possible employment opportunities with a big employer

Tags: management, human-resources, reputation

I have been employed by a large financial institution for a couple of years enjoying decent salary, great bonuses (20% of my salary), matching 401 (k), a pension (!!!) ,  etc, etc.

Unfortunately, my boss (who has been with that bank for over 20 years)  did not bother to properly on-board and train  me: his top priority was to avoid any conflicts and to stay with that bank at all costs: his bonus is 50% of his salary and he plans to retire there at some point.

As the result of the disconnect  I got a horrible performance review, a totally unexpected Performance Improvement Plan (PIP) and, worst of all, he has submitted all that info to the bank's global HR profile  -any division from New York to Sidney has access to my performance profile: that will essentially eliminate my options for re-employment there at some point.

Since he has 20+ years with that Bank, his opinion matters, and I clearly I cannot appeal his decision, so I have quit that job. Obviously, I am upset- because the bank itself is a decent place  and money + benefits+ bonuses of that size are far and between. Is there any way around it, or his submission  of my PIP to the global HR makes me "inadmissible?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That the manager might actually expect quality work in return for the compensation the bank provides?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: Usually, before you get to a PIP, there is a trail of notes in your performance reviews that lead up to that. Have all your previous reviews been good? Or have you been getting negative reviews for your last couple.

Comment: Joe Strazzere: I am afraid that to disappoint you: some of the questions under my profile do not represent MY employment - my friends have asked me to post their questions here.

Comment: I haven't looked at your profile except very briefly, but if some of your questions were asked on behalf of others (nothing wrong with that), then I suggest you edit them to make that clear.

Comment: I wish you hadn't done that, and you had instead told your friends to post under their names/avatars. We do a better job helping those who post under their own names because we get a more consistent narrative out of them.

Comment: If, after "a couple of years", your performance is disappointing enough to see you put on a PIP, can you really put the blame on not being on-boarded properly all those years ago?

Comment: Your question is at best unclear. "_As the result of the disconnect I got a horrible performance review_". What does your manager's disconnect have anything to do with **your** PIP?

Comment: It isn't clear the reason you have to quit your job, just because, you are on a PIP or the reason it's your managers fault after several bonuses in the past

Comment: Frankly you come off as someone who deserved to be put on a PIP. Until you take responsibility for learning what your boss expects and then doing it, you will continue to have employment problems. The very last thing any future emplyer wants to hear is that everything is always someone else's fault. The only person whose behavior you can control is yours. You ran away rather than try to improve, that speaks volumns about you attitude. You don't have to agree with what they want you to do, you have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't want to leave, submit to the performance improvement plan and come out the other end shining.  You haven't been there very long and unless you are being railroaded out turning around your performance will not result in a problem once you've got stellar reports for a few years.

To reiterate, what has been damaged is your immediate upward mobility. And, frankly, in most industries HR plays a small role in people's opinions of coworkers.

Comment: Of course the time to do that ... or to ask for advice ... was before quitting, not after.

Comment: @keshlam, I can't argue with that. Somehow I took the final statement that he was looking for a way around it as having left the position and not the company. Oops. In any case, maybe someone else in a similar position can benefit from my response *before* quitting their position.

Comment: Not criticizing you, @MaxHaaksman. The question's phrasing is confusing, partly because it's an awkward attempt do describe a semi-fictionalized account of someone else's experience using first-person pronouns... and as a result is both somewhat inconsistent and somewhat incomplete.