# CEO unexpectedly resigns

Tags: resignation

We just have learned that the our CEO (I work in the large internet cache optimization company - CDN) has unexpectedly stepped down. Even his direct reports did not know about it. How bad can it be? I know that CEO typically does not leave great companies, yet - is there anything specific that people need to look for or/and do besides start looking for a job?

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons CEOs leave. Many are about the person, who wants to move to a different city or was offered a much better job or has reached whatever goals they had for this job or whatever. Some are about their performance, but then getting a new CEO who performs better would be good news. There just isn't anything useful we can tell you based on "The CEO left." Alone, it's not actionable information.

Comment: I did not say  "The CEO left",. I have said "CEO unexpectedly resigns" -see the difference here? It is the word "unexpected" - we had no indications and his abrupt stepping down was totally shocking.

Comment: Is this the same company that just merged with a smaller one in your [other question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/192253/130734) where you are a "senior director"?

Comment: No more shocking than if your immediate manager unexpectedly announced he was leaving. People sometimes leave unexpectedly due to all sorts of personal reasons that may have nothing to do with the company or the job; all you know right now is that you don't know.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, the CEO is the one doing the layoffs when business is bad, not resigning.

Sudden and unexpected departures by company executives without much notice are very often a result of any of the following:

- Leaving to join a competitor (most likely reason)
- Something scandalous involving other personnel or financial impropriety
- They were actually fired, but their termination was announced as a voluntary resignation

These things happen. The litmus test about the company health isn't based on the CEO leaving. It's what happens next. Look at how the board of directors and other C-suite executives are messaging the go-forward plan to the rest of the company.

Was there a transition plan announced with a lot of flare and positivity? Such as the announcement of someone's promotion to CEO, interim CEO, or a recruiting plan to find a new one? If yes to any of this, that's a good sign.

Have other managers and executive been leaving as well without being replaced? Lots of random re-orgs, layoffs, drop in stock price, or layoff rumors?  These are bad signs.

Comment: It's not change that shows the strength of the company. It's how they deal with it. Nokia did nothing, went bankrupt. Nortel had their IP stolen in their face, did nothing about it, the rest is history.